# How to specify the prefetch strategy and replacement strategy in gem5？

Tags: gem5

In gem5, how to specify a specific prefetch or replacement strategy? Use `./build/X86_MESI_Two_Level/gem5.opt --help` command and no corresponding introduction

Comment: Have you looked into the `m5out/config.ini` file to see where it is specified? And then try to find the point under `config/` where it is being set from.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Ruby does not support any prefetcher other than the one defined in `src/mem/ruby/structures/RubyPrefetcher.hh`.

If you want to use other prefetchers, you will have either to adapt Ruby to use the prefetchers defined in `src/mem/cache/prefetch/` (there is a quick discussion of the theoretical steps needed in https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/27888), or to use the Classic cache. Finally, you can also implement your own prefetchers in Ruby.

Regarding [Replacement Policies](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/memory_system/replacement_policies/), they are located in `src/mem/cache/replacement_policies/`. Both caches use the same name for their respective variable in Python. In Ruby, this variable is declared in RubyCache (`src/mem/ruby/structures/RubyCache.py`). In Classic, it is declared in BaseCache (`src/mem/cache/Cache.py`).

*Please note it is considered a bad practice to directly modify those files to change their variables. You should always create a configuration file for your system, containing your specialized implementations. Check the [documentation](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/simple_config/) for more information on how to create such configurations.*

Comment: thank you for your reply. Ruby is mainly multi-core? In a single-core situation, which classical one is more suitable? Is that correct? My original is in the ruby environment, and I saw a lru replacement strategy. How do you design and choose these replacement algorithms and prefetch strategies?

Comment: These are a lot of different questions. My answers here will be short and vague; you should try to group them into related topics and ask them in the mailing list (or look them up; all of them have been answered already in the mailing list and in gem5.org). In short, Ruby is slower and more precise. Classic gets the job done. Both caches support all replacement policies (src/mem/cache/replacement_policies/). In Classic you define your configuration, re-assigning variables replacement_policy and prefetcher. In Ruby, only replacement_policy can be changed, as answered above.